# text validation help

Tags: jquery-validate

I`m newbie in jquery.

Got the following code:

``

`

How do I validate the textbox for user input required on clicking the button save and display error message next to the save button?

Comment: here we go again, user269431 asking the same question over and over again, but every time just a little different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310477/how-to-verify-duplicate-entry-in-textboxes

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a [Validation Plug-In for jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). Have you looked at this already?

If not, it appears to do exactly what you want, and there is plenty of documentation right there to get started.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Test(txtCheck, lblCheck)
{
    if (txtCheck.value == "")
        lblCheck.innerHTML = "Textbox is empty";
    else
        lblCheck.innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txtCheck" />
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="Test(txtCheck, lblCheck);"/>
    <label id="lblCheck"/>
</body>
```